Streaming audio with python
To help me understand audio streaming, I want to implement a very basic internet radio player, using pyqt, the python bindings to the Qt classes.
The following code produces an appropriate window but no sound.
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.player = QMediaPlayer(None, flags = QMediaPlayer.StreamPlayback)
        media = QUrl("http://wsdownload.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/meta/live/shoutcast/mp3/eieuk.pls")
        content = QMediaContent(media)
        self.player.setMedia(content)
        self.player.play()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow(windowTitle = "Simple internet radio")
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

I can play the stream from the address bar of my browser. Also, the player works if if I substitute a local file for the audio stream, as in:
media = QUrl.fromLocalFile('~/bbc.mp3')  

I conclude that the problem is specifically with the streaming. I am sure that I am missing something (like buffering), but I have been unable to find a working example online. The Qt documentation is very sparse on streaming.
Can anyone please tell me what I am missing?

As the name (and the contents of that file) suggests, that's a playlist, not a stream. Either open its content url by downloading that playlist and copying the stream url, or do that programmatically (you should probably use QNetworkAccessManager).
